# Laravel 5 Password Reset Email Not Being Sent

Tags: php, email, authentication, laravel-5

I am trying to implement a password reset on my Laravel 5.1 app. I have followed the docs (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#resetting-passwords) to get this working. However whenever I click on my 'reset password' button on my `/password/email/` no email is ever sent.

I have intentionally entered incorrect emails and I am getting the appropriate error however when I enter a correct email no email is sent and I get no type of message or any emails.

I have looked at my database and it does looks as though a password reset token being created, just no email is sent.

My email configuration is working properly as other parts of my application sends email properly, only this one section is not sending the emails. Any help will be appreciated as I do not what else to check.

Michael

routes.php:
`

```
// Password reset link request routes...
Route::get('password/email', ['as' => 'password/email', 'uses' => 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail']);
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');

    // Password reset routes...
    Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
    Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@postReset');
```

password.blade.php:

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-section" method="POST" action="/password/email">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
            <span class="pre-input"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></span>
            <input class="name plain buffer" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
            <input id="send" class="plain button yellow" type="submit" value="Reset Password">
              @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
              <font size="3" color="red">{{ $error }}</font>
              @endforeach

          </form>
```

resources/views/emails/password.blade.php:

```
Click here to reset your password: {{ url('password/reset/'.$token) }}
```

**Update**
I have added a Log to the postEmail function.

```
    public function postEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);

    $response = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function (Message $message) {
        $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
 Log::info('Password Reset Execute -1 '); //Does work here


    });

    switch ($response) {

        case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
            return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans($response));

        case Password::INVALID_USER:
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
    }

    Log::info('Password Reset Execute - 2'); //Will not work here
}
```

Comment: Please also post the contents of your email view. You should have one in `resources/views/emails/password.blade.php`

Comment: @maiorano84 I just added that file, however all I did on that was copied and paste the code directly from Laravel site.

Comment: Was the file not there before? Because the existence of that file is required by Auth in order to email anything. Additionally, are you doing this in Homestead or some kind of local VM? Or is this on a public server? Lastly what are your mail settings under `config/mail.php` and your `.env` file?

Comment: @maiorano84  Yes I already had the email view created and in the right location, although I had attempted a run before and of course it threw an error that that view could not be found. I currently have this hosted on a public VM with DigitalOcean. And I have my mail config under `config/mail.php` with the code: `'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mandrill'), `

Comment: Do you receive any errors, or just the email is not sent. Would you check the laravel.log?

Comment: @MinaYoussef No I do not receive any errors and that last item in my log is from yesterday when I did not have the view created, so it looks like the email is just not being sent.

Comment: Are you sure the form is posted correctly?

Comment: @MinaYoussef I belive I do, as I do get the error from the script `We can't find a user with that e-mail address.` if I type a random email into the form.

Comment: Are you sure it's not mandril issue?

Comment: @MinaYoussef I can't say 100 percent it is not an issue with them however I can fill out my contact form which sends an email back to me through mandrill and I am getting it within one minute.

Comment: Personally, I would investigate it further with mandril. Also make sure the email code is being triggered correctly. Place some Log entries in your Password controller.

Comment: @MinaYoussef I just updated my original question with the code I have tried with the log. If the log is after the switch it does not work.

Comment: Yes, because the page is redirected before reaching the Log statement. But seems the message is sent. Did you check mandril?

Comment: @MinaYoussef I have and found the reason it has not being sent is `invalid-sender`. I remember seeing another SO question about changing this so I am going to see if I can track that down.

Comment: @maiorano84 i set it to mandrill and it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the issue is invalid sender, make sure you pass the correct sender

```
$message->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');
```

Comment: I ended up finding and setting up the global setting in the `config/mail.php file`, as I did not want to edit a Laravel file and lose it with a composer update. Thanks for your help Mina!

Comment: You want help on that? Also the update should not change your app files. Only vendor files.

Comment: I found it and everything is working. And the file I have been working with has been a vendor file - `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php`

Answer (score 8):

I added those in .env and password reseting is working again

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xx@xx.xx
MAIL_FROM_NAME=xxxx
```

Comment: This works. For Laravel 5.4, the default don't come with these 2. And in `config/mail.php`, it's set to `hello@example.com`.